# How to Pull Out Twitter Summary Data in other areas of my template?

Tags: custom-field, content, twitter

I am curious on how www.gigaom.com is able to callout the summary data of their articles. In addition I am trying to figure out how the summary autoposts when you select the tweet this button and the author's twitter gets tweeted as well.

I suspect the latter is available via twitter cards, but how can I get the summary data to show before the post content. A custom field? Micro-data?

Here are two examples of what I am talking about...

http://gigaom.com/2013/09/07/from-the-founder-of-aptera-tiny-and-stackable-ultra-efficient-organic-farms/
http://gigaom.com/2013/09/07/an-mlb-photographer-shows-you-how-to-instagram-in-the-big-leagues/

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: How would we know?.. :) My first guess would be they are simply using excerpts for it, but can be done in myriad ways.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. The summary isnt an excerpt of the article in this case.